# How to set ReactiveSearch loader position to top or bottom?

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, next.js, reactivesearch

I'm using ReactiveSearch 3.30.0.

Here's how I use the `ReactiveList` component in my Next.js project.

```
<ReactiveList
 ....
 infiniteScroll={true}
 showLoader={true}
 pagination={false}
 loader={<MyCustomLoader/>}
 ....
/>
```

**The problem is during the loading that occurs,**

- When I click on a filter item
  or
- When Scroll more to the bottom

the `MyCustomLoader` is **always** at the bottom.

**Expected outcome for the `MyCustomLoader` is,**

- When I click on a filter item => `MyCustomLoader` at **top**
  and
- When Scroll more to the bottom => `MyCustomLoader` at **bottom**

The reason is, since my results list is long and scrollable, the loader is not shown  when I click a filter item. It is actually rendered on the DOM, because I could see it when zoomed out the browser window (but is outside visible area to the user).

Related GitHub issue https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch/issues/749

Any workaround is highly appreciated. Thanks.